# RSpec / FactoryGirl - How to pass params in post request spec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

I have a Rails API backend set up with restful routes. I'm trying to pass in parameters for a post request spec, but I've run into some troubles.

In my app a user has many timelines, and a timeline has many entries.
I can correctly create a timeline with a post request by doing the following:

```
post '/timelines', '{ "timeline": { "title":"My timeline", "body":"My timeline body"}}', @token_header
```

The problem i have is when i have to pass more than just string, i.e. an image. My entry model has an `image` attribute, but I can't figure out how to pass in into the parameters.

I have the following test which illustrates what i want to do. As you can see I've declared some entry_attributes but I can't figure out how to correctly pass them as I did with the timeline params.:

```
    context 'POST /timelines/:id/entries' do
          it 'creates an entry for the given timeline' do
            entry_attr = FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:entry)
            post "/timelines/#{@timeline.id}/entries", {}, @token_header

            expect(response.status).to eq 201
          end
    end
```

Any help is greatly appreciated...

Comment: Something like that should do: `post "/timelines/#{@timeline.id}/entries", entry_attr, @token_header`. If you need to explicitly pass a json in string, then simply pass `entry_attr.to_json`